# How to get a polynomial corresponding to a solvable Galois group of order 60?

Tags: galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Of course, we know the $A_5$ of $60$ order is an unsolvable group. But as the [wiki here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvable_group#OEIS_values), there are also $12$ solvable groups in the same $60$ order still:
[image]

Then I have generated many many irreducible polynomials whose Galois group is $60$ order with [maple program](https://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/234226-How-To-Generate-A-Polynomial-Corresponding) to check, but none of them is solvable. What's wrong?

Is there a solvable polynomial whose Galois group is $60$ order? If it exists, can you please give any example?

Comment: It doesn't work with degree $5$, because $S_5$ has no transitive subgroup of order $60$ except for $A_5$. But it works for degree $15$, see the table [here](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/T31.html). For example the solvable group $C_3⋊F_5$, where $F_5$ is the Frobenius group of order $20$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The irreducible polynomial
$$
x^{15}-30x^{10}-3708x^5-2
$$
has Galois group
$$
C_3\rtimes F_5,
$$
which is solvable of order $60$. Here $F_5$ is the Frobenius group of order $20$.

Reference: The tables [here](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ematyd/GroupNames/T31.html).

Comment: How did you obtain the polynomial by backpropagation from the Galois group? Does such an algorithm exist?

Comment: No, in general  reverse engineering is very difficult. In fact, the [Inverse Galois Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Galois_problem) is still open in general. But here you can try to obtain an action of the Galois group on a suitable field, and then find the minimal polynomial of a primitive element.

Comment: In fact to find the solvable group of order 60 I have [a simpler method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mrfgu.png) than looking up the table in *Mathematica*. I just don't know how to construct the polynomial corresponding to it by these groups. As you said, this could be quite difficult. But can we be sure at the moment that polynomials of these groups are necessarily all exist?

Comment: Yes, the transitive groups of order $60$ are just known. In this case, irreducible polynomials are also known, see the status of the Inverse Galois Problem, what is known and what is unknown.